# Error in running Cordova apps in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

When I make a new typescript Cordova application in Visual Studio, a page comes open with:

> Please fix the following issues to ensure that your app builds and runs successfully.
>
> Android SDK : The override value set on the Environment Variable Option Page pointed to an invalid or nonexistent location for this software.

When I run the app with `ripple -Nexus` (Galaxy), in error list I have 2 errors:

> Please install Android targer " Android-19 "
>
> cmd: Command failed with exit code 8

Does anyone have the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not installed the SDK right!

click "Start" and look for "Android SDK Tools" - "SDK Manager", under "Tools", the following should be installed:

1. Android SDK Tools
2. Android SDK Platform Tools
3. Android SDK Build Tools for rev 19.1

Then install everything inside Android 4.4.2 (API 19)

If you cannot find SDK Manager, which means that you did not install Cordova correctly.

If you are using Visual Studio 2013 Community Update 4, you need to install Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.1

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 Community RC, you need to select "Tools for Apache Cordova" during the installation of VS 2015.

If you are inside China or some other countries that block access to Google, you need to make sure you can access dl.google.com before you install Tools for Apache Cordova.

If you think that you install everything properly and still get the error, in Visual Studio, go to "Tools" - "Options" - "Tools for Apache Cordova" - "Environment Variables Override" and check the ADT_HOME variable, is your Android SDK installed in the path stated in the ADT_HOME?

Still not ok?  in "Tools" - "Options" - "Tools for Apache Cordova", use "Clear Cordova Cache", then the system hangs about a minute or two, then it will ok, and you can rebuild again.

Comment: in ADT_HOME write SDK address or ADT Address?

Comment: sdk address, you don't need to enable this if you install everything correctly